# Best way converting data in PANDAS DataFrame to matrix in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I found one thread of converting a [matrix to das pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002720/python-converting-pandas-matrix-to-dataframe). However, I would like to do the opposite - I have a pandas DataFrame with time series data of this structure:

```
row time stamp, batch, value
1, 1, 0.1
2, 1, 0.2
3, 1, 0.3
4, 1, 0.3
5, 2, 0.25
6, 2, 0.32
7, 2, 0.2
8, 2, 0.1
...
```

What I would like to have is a matrix of values with one row belonging to one batch:

```
[[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3],
[0.25, 0.32, 0.2, 0.1],
...]
```

which I want to plot as heatmap using matplotlib or alike.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is to first group by the desired index:

```py
g = df.groupby("batch")
```

And then convert this group to an array by aggregating using the `list` constructor.
The result can then be converted to an array using the `.values` property (or `.as_matrix()` function, but this is getting deprecated soon.)

```py
mtr = g.aggregate(list).values
```

One downside of this method is that it will create arrays of lists instead of a nice array, even if the result would lead to a non-jagged array.

Alternatively, if you know that you get exactly 4 values for every unique value of `batch` you can just use the matrix directly.

```
df = df.sort_values("batch")
my_indices = [1, 2] # Or whatever indices you desire.
mtr = df.values[:, my_indices] # or df.as_matrix()
mtr = mtr.reshape(-1, 4) # Only works if you have exactly 4 values for each batch
```

Comment: Hi amdex, this seems to work. The only problem I still have is that the "row time" are as well part of the output list together with the actual values. Is there a way to remove these "row time" entries so that only the values are part of the matrix?

Comment: Right, sorry, I did not consider this. You can select your desired columns after your groupby call. e.g. `g["value"].aggregate(list).values` will select only "value".

Answer (score 0):

Try and use crosstab from pandas, pd.crosstab(). You will have to confirm the aggfunction.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html

and then .as_matrix()